# Why NDSolve's default method fails in solving this ODE system?

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, numerics, options

Recently, someone showed me the following ODE system for a try in Mathematica's `NDSolve`,

```
eqns={z'[t]==-2 Sin[θ[t]] (1-(3 ξ1[t]^2)/1000),
θ'[t]==z[t] (12+(2 Cos[θ[t]] (1-(3 ξ1[t]^2)/1000))/Sqrt[1-z[t]^2]),
ξ1'[t]==3000 Cos[ϕ1[t]]-50 ξ1[t]-50 Sin[ϕ1[t]-ϕ2[t]] ξ2[t],ϕ1'[t]==300-1000 (1/250+(3 Cos[θ[t]] Sqrt[1-z[t]^2])/1000)-(3000 Sin[ϕ1[t]])/ξ1[t]-(50 Cos[ϕ1[t]-ϕ2[t]] ξ2[t])/ξ1[t],ξ2'[t]==50 Sin[ϕ1[t]-ϕ2[t]] ξ1[t]+50 ξ2[t],ϕ2'[t]==300-(50 Cos[ϕ1[t]-ϕ2[t]] ξ1[t])/ξ2[t]}


ibcs={z[0] == 7/10, θ[0] == 0, ξ1[0] == 107/10, ξ2[0] == 
  107/10, ϕ1[0] == π/2, ϕ2[0] == π/2}
```

But `NDsolve`'s default settings:

`sol = NDSolve[{eqns,ibcs}, {z, θ, ξ1, ξ2, ϕ1, ϕ2}, {t, Pi}]`

does not solve this system.

**The default NDSolve setting as above does not work properly**(This is what causes my courisity): it is very demanding in CPU time and memory, and obtains poor/wrong numerical results in a very limited interval of $t$, e.g., $t\in[0,0.01]$ with warning message like: `maximum steps reached at 0.01`.

I have to try to specify the `Method` option of `NDSolve` in order to solve it easily. For example **When using the following option, it works!**:

`Method->{"ExplicitRungeKutta","Coefficients" ->"EmbeddedExplicitRungeKuttaCoefficients","DifferenceOrder" -> 5,"StiffnessTest" -> False};`

which gives:
[image]

I also tried Matlab's `ode45`, and found the system could be easily solved by its default options settings:

```
function tryODE45
options = odeset('RelTol',1e-4,'AbsTol',1e-4*ones(1,6));
t0=[(7/10),0,(107/10),(107/10),(1/2)*pi,(1/2)*pi];
[T,Y] = ode45(@odeEqns,[0 .35],t0,options);
figure,
subplot(231),plot(T,Y(:,1),'r'),title('z');
subplot(232),plot(T,Y(:,2),'b'),title('\theta');
subplot(233),plot(T,Y(:,3),'m'),title('\xi_1');
subplot(234),plot(T,Y(:,4),'b'),title('\xi_2');
subplot(235),plot(T,Y(:,5),'g'),title('\phi_1');
subplot(236),plot(T,Y(:,6),'b'),title('\phi_2');

function dy=odeEqns(~,y)
dy = zeros(6,1);    % a column vector
dy(1)=-2*sin(y(2))*(1+(-3/1000)*y(3)^2);
dy(2)=y(1)*(12+2*cos(y(2))*(1+(-1)*y(1)^2)^(-1/2)*(1+(-3/1000)*y(3)^2));
dy(3)=(3000*cos(y(5))+(-50)*y(3)+(-50)*sin(y(5)+(-1)*y(6))*y(4));
dy(4)=(50*sin(y(5)+(-1)*y(6))*y(3)+50*y(4));
dy(5)=(300+(-1000)*((1/250)+(3/1000)*cos(y(2))*(1+(-1)*y(1)^2)^(1/2))+(-3000)*sin(y(5))*y(3)^(-1)+(-50)*cos(y(5)+(-1)*y(6))*y(3)^(-1)*y(4));
dy(6)=(300+(-50)*cos(y(5)+(-1)*y(6))*y(3)*y(4)^(-1));
```

[image]

My question is: why `NDSolve` has problem when handling such an ODE system? Is there any hint or tricks in order to properly use `NDSolve` in future cases?

Comment: Does `NDSolve` give an error?  If so, what is it?

Comment: Note that the code does not seem to have been copied correctly, the derivatives in particular. You may find [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful.

Comment: Does it work without `"StiffnessTest" -> False`?  That feels like a hint to me.  -- Why does the *Mathematica* code ask for a solution out to `t == Pi`, but the MATLAB code only goes up to `0.35`? The default for *Mathematica* works fine if I set the time limit to `0.35`.

Comment: Thank you @MichaelE2. Because there are many Greek symbols, I use http://steampiano.net/msc/ to convert them. This might be the reason to the issues you mentioned. -- This is a very simple ODE problem if using Matlab or `NDSolve` with the method options I proposed: delivering results almost instantly. While the default `NDSolve` does not work and gives warning message like: `maximum steps reached at 0.01 `.

Comment: It's primarily the derivatives `(z^\[Prime]([y]` etc. You've copied the formatted output, but for it to work when it's pasted back into *Mathematica*, it needs to be posted in `InputForm`. The Greek letters weren't a problem. -- I got the same error (~14+M steps up to `t == 0.68`!), but I believe it's because the interval of integration is so much longer in the first *Mathematica* code than in the plots or in the MATLAB code. As the frequency of the oscillations increase, the step size has to get smaller. You can set `MaxSteps -> Infinity`, but it will probably use up to much memory.

Comment: If I use your `"ExplicitRungeKutta"` method options, it fails sooner, at `t == 0.426`: http://i.stack.imgur.com/GueyO.png

Comment: @MichaelE2 Warning message is not the major problem: the numerical results returned is usually wrong if you visualize them by `Plot[Evaluate[#[t] /. First@sol], {t, 0, .3},  PlotStyle -> Red] & /@ {z, \[Theta], \[Xi]1, \[Xi]2, \[Phi]1, \[Phi]2}`

Comment: I get this, http://i.stack.imgur.com/jMqIO.png, which seems indistinguishable from the MATLAB output posted.  What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To clarify my comments, I thought I'd post the complete code I'm using.  As of now, I don't see a problem.  The main difference between the OP's results is that the OP's first code integrates over the interval `{t, 0, Pi}`, but in the plots and MATLAB code, the interval of integration only goes up to `t == 0.35`.  That's a huge difference.  The step size at `t = 0.35` is already down to `2.90964*10^-6` due to the high frequency of oscillations of `z[t]`.  I also find that neither the default setting not the Runge-Kutta option can integrate out to `t == Pi`; in fact, the RK method gives up sooner than the default (LSODA).

```
eqns = {(z')[t] == -2 Sin[θ[t]] (1 - (3 ξ1[t]^2)/1000),
   (θ')[t] == z[t] (12 + (2 Cos[θ[t]] (1 - (3 ξ1[t]^2)/1000))/Sqrt[1 - z[t]^2]),
   (ξ1')[t] == 3000 Cos[ϕ1[t]] - 50 ξ1[t] - 50 Sin[ϕ1[t] - ϕ2[t]] ξ2[t],
   (ϕ1')[t] == 300 - 1000 (1/250 + (3 Cos[θ[t]] Sqrt[1 - z[t]^2])/1000) -
     (3000 Sin[ϕ1[t]])/ξ1[t] - (50 Cos[ϕ1[t] - ϕ2[t]] ξ2[t])/ξ1[t],
   (ξ2')[t] == 50 Sin[ϕ1[t] - ϕ2[t]] ξ1[t] + 50 ξ2[t],
   (ϕ2')[t] == 300 - (50 Cos[ϕ1[t] - ϕ2[t]] ξ1[t])/ξ2[t]};

ibcs = {z[0] == 7/10, θ[0] == 0, ξ1[0] == 107/10, ξ2[0] == 107/10,
   ϕ1[0] == π/2, ϕ2[0] == π/2};

{sol} = NDSolve[{eqns, ibcs}, {z, θ, ξ1, ξ2, ϕ1, ϕ2},
    {t,(*Pi*)0.35}]; // AbsoluteTiming
ByteCount@sol
(*
  {0.041426, Null}
  1256632
*)

GraphicsGrid@Partition[
  Plot[#, {t, 0, 0.35}, PlotStyle -> Red] & /@ 
   Through[{z, θ, ξ1, ξ2, ϕ1, ϕ2}[t] /. sol],
  3]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Ich spreche kein Matlab, but is OP's `options = odeset('RelTol',1e-4,'AbsTol',1e-4*ones(1,6));` equivalent to `AccuracyGoal->4, PrecisionGoal->4`?  If so, that speeds up the Mathematica code about three times, while still producing similar graphs.

Comment: @ChrisK I don't know much Matlab, but that seems to be correct, although it seems to use them in a different way. In Matlab, the condition is `error < max(RelTol*abs(y(i)), AbsTol(i))` and in *Mathematica* it's equivalent to the sum instead of `max`.

Comment: Thank you! It seems to be this reason. According to the documents of `NDSolve`, there are also similar implementation as matlab's ode45 in NDSolve.

Comment: @user6043040 You're welcome!